# Como puedo obtener ultimo registro por fecha y tiempo

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quisiera obtener el ultimo valor registrado en una tabla, existen dos columnas en mi tabla FECHA y TIEMPO. ¿como puedo consultar a la base para que me regrese por ejemplo el dato '8' de la columna valor?

> Estructura de mi tabla

```
id_log_influ    id_usuario  valor     FECHA             TIEMPO
    1               2         6      2018-09-24      09:43:03.0000000
    1               4         8      2018-09-24      10:52:03.0000000
```

> Tipo de dato

```
valor --> varchar
FECHA --> date
TIEMPO --> time
```

Comment: Sería interesante saber el tipo de dato que has utilizado al crear la estructura de tu tabla, para así poder saber si es necesario hacer alguna conversión, como sugerencia.

Comment: Juan Manuel edite mi pregunta, espero me puedas apoyar, gracias!

Comment: Justamente, sobre los tipos de dato que mencionas, si es SQL-Server lo que estas utilizando, el tipo de dato "date" y "time" no son validos, ambos campos deberían ser "datetime". Dejando eso de lado, al realizar la consulta y utilizando el "order by" adecuado, podrás obtener lo que buscas.

Comment: Tienes que hacer uso de la clausula TOP ordenando de manera descendente. Pueden revsar esta liga que te comparto. http://www.respuestasit.com.mx/2015/12/uso-de-order-by-top-percent-en-sql.html

Comment: Gracias Juan Manuel, efectivamente con un cast sobre Fecha y tiempo se soluciono mi duda...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que buscas es obtener el último `Valor` de un registro de una fecha dada dependiendo del campo `Fecha` y `Tiempo`.

Lo que debes hacer es seleccionar el campo `Valor` del primer registro, ordenado por el campo `Tiempo` de manera descendente, que cumpla con la condición donde el campo `Fecha` sea lo que indiques, en nuestro ejemplo `2018-09-24`.

```
--id_log_influ    id_usuario  valor     FECHA             TIEMPO
--    1               2         6      2018-09-24      09:43:03.0000000
--    1               4         8      2018-09-24      10:52:03.0000000

CREATE TABLE #TABLATEMPORAL (
    ID_LOG_INFLU    INT,
    ID_USUARIO      INT,
    VALOR           INT,
    FECHA           DATE,
    TIEMPO          TIME
);

INSERT INTO #TABLATEMPORAL
VALUES  (1, 2, 6, '2018-09-24', '09:43:03'), 
        (1, 4, 8, '2018-09-24', '10:52:03'),
        (2, 2, 5, '2018-09-26', '12:52:03');

SELECT TOP(1) VALOR
FROM #TABLATEMPORAL
WHERE FECHA = '2018-09-24'  --AQUI USA UNA VARIABLE Y MANDARIAS LA FECHA
ORDER BY TIEMPO DESC

DROP TABLE #TABLATEMPORAL;
```

Si por el contrario solo quieres el ultimo `Valor` registrado de tu tabla, solo usa un simple `SELECT` de esta manera, sumando el campo `Fecha` y el campo `Tiempo` para luego ordenarlo de manera descendente:

```
--id_log_influ    id_usuario  valor     FECHA             TIEMPO
--    1               2         6      2018-09-24      09:43:03.0000000
--    1               4         8      2018-09-24      10:52:03.0000000

CREATE TABLE #TABLATEMPORAL (
    ID_LOG_INFLU    INT,
    ID_USUARIO      INT,
    VALOR           INT,
    FECHA           DATE,
    TIEMPO          TIME
);

INSERT INTO #TABLATEMPORAL
VALUES  (1, 2, 6, '2018-09-24', '09:43:03'), 
        (1, 4, 8, '2018-09-24', '10:52:03'),
        (2, 2, 5, '2018-09-26', '12:52:03');

SELECT TOP(1) VALOR
FROM #TABLATEMPORAL
ORDER BY CAST(FECHA AS DATETIME) + CAST(TIEMPO AS DATETIME) DESC

DROP TABLE #TABLATEMPORAL;
```

Comment: Para el ejemplo que mencionas, trate de replicarlo y tuve que cambiar los tipos de datos del campo Fecha a DateTime y del campo Tiempo a Char(8), luego de eso el ejemplo funcionó perfectamente, incluso modifiqué algunos valores para corroborar los resultados.

Comment: Lo siento no te pregunte como estabas guardando tus campos `Fecha` y `Tiempo`, si la respuesta te ayudo marcala como válida para que otra persona pueda usarla. Podías solo haber casteado los 2 campos a `DATETIME` al final es solo un `String` así como lo hice en el segundo ejemplo.

Comment: No hay problema, yo no formulé la pregunta inicial, solo he comentado al respecto, para poder aclarar cualquier duda adicional por los diferentes tipos de dato que existen. Tu respuesta está bastante bien, como he comentado antes, sólo tuve que hacer esos ajustes mínimos.

Comment: @VictorPerdomo te agradezco, efectivamente el uso de ORDER BY y CAST funciono correctamente, en el caso especifico que quiera consultar el ultimo registro de un usuario en la tabla solo coloco antes del order by un where con su id cierto?

Comment: Si solo agregas el `WHERE` con el id del usuario.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT max(CONCAT(FECHA, ,TIEMPO)) from tabla ;
```

De esta manera posiblemente te pueda servir, lo que hacemos es concatenar los dos campos y sacar el maximo valor de esa union.

Espero funcione.

Answer (score 2):

De este modo sería la consulta (disculpa actualicé pues no había visto que usas sql server)

```
 SELECT valor, CONCAT(fecha, tiempo) as mayor 
 from registro 
 ORDER BY valor
 OFFSET 1 ROWS;
```

Toma en cuenta que como según tu pregunta te interesa mostrar el registro de la columna valor debes escribirla de manera explicita en tu consulta para que al final solo te muestre: `valor tiempo mas grande(max)`

> Además de eso se usará la función `CONCAT` para unir varios valores
>   separados por comas, como en tu enunciado indicas que deseas obtener
>   el valor mayor por `fecha` y `tiempo`, por eso se hace necesaria esta
>   función, yo le anexe un espacio vacio en medio entre comillas simples
>   únicamente para que al momento de que se muestra la consulta no se
>   vean pegados los nombres de las columnas

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas siempre obtener el ultimo valor de tu tabla puedes realizar lo siguiente
En tu tabla tu idimcrementable lo pondremos que es valor para el ejemplo

```
declare @ultimovalor
set @ultimovalor =(select max(valor) from tabla)

select * from tabla where valor=@ultimovalor
```

con este script ya siempre te va aparecer el ultimo registro de tu tabla

espero haberte ayudado.!!